# How can i export mysql table to csv file and download it

Tags: php, drupal

Am tryng to export data to csv file from mysql. I took the following script but the $result variable have error : mysql_num_fields tells the argument supplied is not valid

```
$filename = 'myfile.csv';
$result = db_query("SELECT * FROM {loreal_salons}");


drupal_set_header('Content-Type: text/csv');
drupal_set_header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);

$count = mysql_num_fields($result);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $header[] = mysql_field_name($result, $i);
}
print implode(',', $header) . "\r\n";

while ($row = db_fetch_array($result)) {
    foreach ($row as $value) {
        $values[] = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', decode_entities(strip_tags($value))) . '"';
    }
    print implode(',', $values) . "\r\n";
    unset($values);
}
```

Comment: What are those curly brackets for?

Comment: that's for drupal. no problem ther.

Comment: I'd guess the brackets are still causing the issue.  Do you have other queries into that table?  Do they execute correctly?  If not try backtick-quoting the table name like so: `\`{lreal_salons}\``

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind using a temporary file, you can do:

```
SELECT *
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/myfile.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM loreal_salons
```

as your query, then simply do:

```
header('Content-type: text/csv');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=myfile.csv');
readfile('/tmp/myfile.csv');
unlink('/tmp/myfile.csv');
exit();
```

Comment: Will there be a problem with file/folder permissions? Can mysqld write inside file/folders owned by httpd?

Comment: MySQL will only write out to a place it has write permissions, and will not overwrite an existing file (to prevent an injection attack from being able to overwrite other files). You could set up a dedicated directory and put httpd and mysql into a group that has write permissions on that directory.